# How to make the dog in Minecraft stand up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I think it happens because I left him in my old base and because the place is not flat. I searched for a place where I can build a farm, and after 4 days (in real life) I came back to the place where I left my dog, but for some reason I can't make him stand. Right-clicking doesn't work.
When I place water under him, he stands up and attacks me, and when the water is gone, he sits again, and I still can't tell him to stand up; even when I give him meat he still attacks me when I place water under him.

Can you tell me how can I let the dog stand? What should I do?

He's growling like he's angry, but his eyes are not red.
I want to bring my dog to my new base.

Comment: Does he have a Red band around his neck?

Comment: @Joachim the dog is sitting, OP wants to make it stand up to let it follow

Comment: Are you sure it is your dog and not someone else's?

Comment: Are you playing on a snapshot? Because I have seen problems similar to this, and the cause of those peoples' issues was because of converting a world to a snapshot version.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to re-tame the wolf.

If you created the world in a different version of Minecraft than you are running the world in, then the world very possibly could be corrupted and hopefully you have a backup world. Also release version worlds and snapshot version worlds are not very compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a corrupted world. He might be set to be tamed, but has no tag saying who tamed him. This is my best guess, but I can't say for sure. You could try a previous version if you recently updated, but I cannot say for sure. It is certainly a strange issue, and not one I have run into before

Comment: Hey @kbd welcome to Arqade, thank you for your response but I'm fearful if community allows guesses and suggestions as answers, you can definitely add comments with suggestion. I'm indeed grateful for your answer but this answer might not answer OP's question and you might end up getting downvotes.

Comment: Unfortunately he has not given enough information to tell for sure what is going on.